# How to filter elements by data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code for filtering/searching specific elements. I need to make it work with data attributes.

For example:

```
<i data-eva="icon"></i>
```

Currently is looking for text and I need to make it look for the value of data-eva="".

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#myTable tr").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: try this
`$("i").attr("data-eva")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using JQuery you can select by data tag like this:

```js
$("i[data-eva=icon]")
```

Or get the data tag value as below:

```js
$("i").attr("data-eva")
```

**Edit:**
Example Code Updated.

In javascript section:

- `$("#myInput")` determines your search input elements id.
- `$("#tab1 .card")` determines the elements that will be hidden or shown according to the search term.
- In `find("i")` the `i` determines the element which has the data tag.
- And obviously in `attr("data-eva")`, `data-eva` is the data tag that will be searched.

You can change the any of above selector according to your needs.

Snippet below searches the elements with class `card` in rows according to `data-eva` of `i` in each row and hide those that does not match the input term.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#tab1 .card").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).find("i").attr("data-eva").toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<h2>Filterable rows by data tag</h2>
<p>Type something in the input field to search for one of the available data tags (<b>icon1</b> for green buttons and <b>icon2</b> for blue one):</p>

<input id="myInput" type="search" placeholder="Search">
<div class="tab-content" id="myTable">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="tab1" role="tabpanel">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="card"> <button class="btn btn-success"><i data-eva="icon1">Button1</i></button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="card"> <button class="btn btn-info"><i data-eva="icon2">Button2</i>                  </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="card"> <button class="btn btn-success"><i data-eva="icon1">Button3</i></button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="card"> <button class="btn btn-success"><i data-eva="icon1">Button4</i>                  </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: I will but I need better explanation of where data tag is needed in your code.

Comment: Here's an example of similar thing working with table.

https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_filters_table

Comment: Added an example with searching data tags. If you specify where your data tags will be I can edit it to match what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I've tried this but it's not working.

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#myTable button").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).attr("data-eva").toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});

Comment: Here is my html

<input id="myInput" type="search" placeholder="Search">

<div class="tab-content" id="myTable">
<div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="tab1" role="tabpanel">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
<div class="card">
<button><i data-eva="icon1"></i></button>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
<div class="card">
<button><i data-eva="icon2"></i></button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

Comment: The code you have posted looks like a bootstrap tab. I do not understand the goal here. For example if  `icon1` is typed in the input it will only show the tabs that have `data-eva="icon1"` ?

Comment: Yes, don't worry. I have 200+ icons.

Comment: The code is updated and explained according to your example code. Let me know if further explanation is needed.

Comment: I keep getting this error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (filter.js:5)
    at jquery-slim.min.js:2
    at Function.grep (jquery-slim.min.js:2)
    at L (jquery-slim.min.js:2)
    at w.fn.init.filter (jquery-slim.min.js:2)
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (filter.js:4)
    at HTMLInputElement.dispatch (jquery-slim.min.js:2)
    at HTMLInputElement.v.handle (jquery-slim.min.js:2)